# Not able to load image from URI from registerForActivityResult()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to load images from gallery and camera into the imageview using Glider.

*** FIXED ***

I dont know how to handle the URI. I have attached the URI which i am getting from gallery and camera

Camera: `/my_images/Pictures/JPEG_20200806_213840_4160667046172070294.jpg`
(I can view the image in the directory)

Gallery: `/document/msf:24`

```
 fun openGallery(){
        val takeimageg = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){
            it?.also {
                ToastMessage("${it.path}")
                recentPagerViewModel.setImage(it,"Gallery")
            }
        }
        takeimageg.launch("image/*")
    }
```

```
    fun openCamera(){
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        val photoFile: File? = try {
            createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ToastMessage("Error Creating File")
            null
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        photoFile?.also {
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                it
            )
            takeimage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()){success ->
                if(success){
                    ToastMessage("${photoURI.path}")
                    recentPagerViewModel.setImage(photoURI , "Camera")
                }
            }
            takeimage.launch(photoURI)

        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File? = context?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }
```

```
Glide.with(this)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(
                    RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .load(it) // Chnaged to it from it.path
                .into(imgview)
```

Comment: That is not the uri. Your uri should be a content scheme. Use data.getData().toString().

Comment: what format does URI need to have ? The app crashes by saying data(intent) is null onactivityresult @blackapps

Comment: Then where do you see the mentioned 'paths'?

Comment: And i see no onActivityResult code.